# Two Prompts - bash

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a prompt that would be like this:

*script:* Enter the file name

*user:* **data.pdf**

*script:* Enter the **amount** of **data.pdf** you want

*user:* **2**

then it **ouputs 2 data.pdf's** in my output file, here is what I am currently trying but it it's not working:

```
 PROMPT_TEXT='Enter the filename:'
 PROMPT_TEXT='Enter the Number of that files you want outputted'
 read -p "$PROMPT_TEXT" filename
 read -p "$PROMPT_TEXT" amount
 grep -m "$amount" "$filename" input.txt > output.csv
 echo "**Stored Successfully in output.txt**";;
```

here is the input file if it helps:

```
FilePath  Filename  Probability ClassifierID    HectorFileType  LibmagicFileType
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 01d0cd964020a1f498c601f9801742c1    19  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 0299a1771587043b232f760cbedbb5b7    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wait until you've read the file name to create the second prompt:

```
PROMPT_TEXT='Enter the filename:'
read -p "$PROMPT_TEXT" filename
PROMPT_TEXT="Enter the amount of $filename you want outputted"
read -p "$PROMPT_TEXT" amount
grep -m "$amount" "$filename" input.txt > output.csv
echo "**Stored Successfully in output.txt**"
```

Comment: "enter the amount of $filename" does not work probably because it thinks $ is part of the text but the script works perfectly, thank you

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the single quotes to double quotes, which will allow `$filename` to expand.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what the issue was. I assume that you're getting the same prompt twice. You need to define both prompts as separate variables:

```
PROMPT_TEXT1='Enter the filename:'
PROMPT_TEXT2='Enter the Number of that files you want outputted'
read -p "$PROMPT_TEXT1" filename
read -p "$PROMPT_TEXT2" amount
grep -m "$amount" "$filename" input.txt > output.csv
echo "**Stored Successfully in output.txt**";;
```

Or, just do away with them entirely:

```
read -p "Enter the filename:" filename
read -p "Enter the Number of that files you want outputted:" amount
grep -m "$amount" "$filename" input.txt > output.csv
echo "**Stored Successfully in output.txt**";;
```